# Span a DataGridCell when the width of text is more than width of column

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

How can I use the right empty cell(s) in a DataGrid to show continue text if the content of the left cell is greater than its width?

In case of the right cell has data, it is OK to use `TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"`

```
------------------------------
|   Name   |    Last Name     |
-------------------------------
| Looooo...|  a last name     |
-------------------------------

But if the right cell is empty, something like:

-------------------------------
|   Name   |    Last Name     |
-------------------------------
| Loooooooong Nameeeeee       |
-------------------------------
```

Is there any property to make the text like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use Grid instead of DataGrid.

then add a property to your class, like TextIsLong

add a DataTrigger to ItemTemplate, to check whether or not TextIsLong is true, and if it's true, set Grid.ColumnSpan of that TextBlock to 2

Comment: After research, I found that ZIndex would be used at this case. I could create a text box and link it to the cell. The textbox's zIndex will be bigger than the datagrid. But I do not know how to dock the textbox into the cell so that when I scroll the datagrid, the textbox is moved along with the cell.

Comment: if you place the text in a canvas in that cell, and make the canvas wide enough, would it be shown over the adjacent cell?